# Eloquent relationship to get grandparents, great grandparents, etc

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table "people" with these fields :

- Name
- mother_id
- father_id

In `mother_id` and `father_id`, I stock other `Poeple` ID

I have two relationships to get the parents

```
public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Poeple::class, 'father_id');
}

public function mother()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Poeple::class, 'mother_id');
}
```

Since I can pick up the parents directly, I wonder if it is possible with Eloquent and Laravel to recover the parents of the parents, the parents of the grandparents, etc.

Is there a relationship to do that? Or a tip?

I do not know if it's possible to do:

- I look if the child has a parent.
- If he has a parent, I look if his parent has a grandparents
- And so on (maximum 4)

At the end, I create a collection with all that. It's possible ?

Nested set does not seem to work for me. I have two parents.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered looking at nested sets?

Comment: There isn't a relationship in laravel to do that directory. It sounds like you might want something called nested sets. https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: @RossWilson Nested set would not work in my case, I have two parents. It is not possible to inherit in each parent? I'm looking at whether the item to a parent, if so, I'm looking if his parent has another parent, and I'm creating a collection ...?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple trick you can achieve this.

use `$appends`

```
protected $appends = ['father'];


public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Poeple::class, 'father_id');
}

public function mother()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Poeple::class, 'mother_id');
}
```

Above code will give you the nested results with every collection.

Comment: I do not know $append.I can not find information on it. It really helps to collect all nested results?

Comment: @Jeremy Yess it will give nested results all the related models too